# list of default packages for Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: gnome, package-management, default-programs

I wanted to remove everything related to `wine` and I ran this line:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine*
```

For some reason, it started to remove a whole bunch of essential graphical (or even not) packages, which I then stopped from being removed when it was already half way through.

Now, I reinstalled `gnome`, but windows have an odd appearance. There is definitely something still missing.

Is there any list of **"default" packages** for Ubuntu 12.10 which I could check and possibly install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

restart and see if that works. Otherwise install these:

```
sudo apt-get install account-plugin-windows-live aisleriot alarm-clock-applet apt-transport-https apturl autopoint brasero brasero-cdrkit chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg compiz compiz-gnome curl deja-dup-backend-gvfs devhelp devhelp-common emacs24 evolution-data-server flashplugin-installer gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-muffin-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 git gksu gnome-contacts gnome-shell gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-share gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gvfs-backends ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table inkscape kerneloops-daemon libbonoboui2-0 libbrasero-media3-1 libcmis-0.3-3 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdevhelp-3-1 libfolks-eds25 libgconf2-4 libgdata13 libgksu2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgnomevfs2-extra libgssapi3-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libldap-2.4-2 libmuffin0 liboauth0 libquvi7 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-es libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-writer librhythmbox-core6 libslv2-9 libsmbclient libtotem-plparser17 libtotem0 libwind0-heimdal lightdm-remote-session-uccsconfigure muffin-common mythes-en-us nautilus-share network-manager-gnome octave octave-miscellaneous python-cupshelpers python-gconf python-pycurl python-smbc python3-uno rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone samba-common-bin seahorse smbclient software-center system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins ubuntu-desktop ubuntuone-client-gnome unity unity-chromium-extension unity-lens-photos unity-scope-musicstores unity-tweak-tool vim-gnome virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse webaccounts-chromium-extension whoopsie
```

(You might want to not install some of these, for example I use `virtualbox` and the wildcard you used also caught it. Of course, you could remove it and others you don't use once your system is OK.)

**Edit:**

You should specify

```
sudo apt-get remove wine.*
```

The pattern `apt-get` expects is a regex, when you write `wine*` you are telling it to match:

- the string `"win"`;
- the string `"wine"`;
- the string `"winee"`;
- the string `"wineee"`;
- etc.

That is because `*` (asterisk) appended to a character means the character should repeat zero or more times. The dot in `wine.*` means any non-vertical-space character, in particular `wine.*` tries to match:

- the string `"wine"`
- any string which contains the word `"wine"` followed by one character or more.

Nonetheless for better results you should do

```
wine_packages=$(apt-cache --names-only search 'wine.*' | awk '{ print $1 }')
sudo apt-get remove $wine_packages
```

Of course, there are still some packages which aren't Wine related there... The best is just to uninstall them one at a time and running `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why by specifying `wine*` I was about do remove so much stuff?

Comment: I've edited my question to include this.

Comment: Also if you've answered the question, please add the solution you've reached or mark my solution as accepted (if my answer solved it). That way it helps others.